# TensorFlow without jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Do I absolutely need to use jupyter notebook to run TensorFlow in Windows ?
I tried the detect object example with the jupyter notebook, it works but I'm not really comfortable, Im used to notepad++ and running python directly on my windows without virtual environment.
I tried to copy past all the codes but I run into many hugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not compulsory to use Jupyter notebook to run Tensorflow on Windows. I personally use PyCharm as my IDE and Anaconda for dependency management (this is completely optional).

I would recommend you to use a proper IDE instead of notepad++ because it's much easier to do debugging using an IDE. You'll also be cloning a lot from Git when you start developing your own model, and usually the open source models out there has a lot of classes and methods in it (take Google's Inception net for example).

Another alternative would be maybe you can start posting about the bugs you are facing, then we can all start helping you.

Comment: OMG, PyCharm is the bomb !!! actually i use android studio extensively, so i'm used to the interface and shortcuts etc !!!

Comment: PyCharm and android studio are both developed by JetBrains along with some other IDEs. You should check them out.